# React Bootstrap labels not sizing correctly

Tags: reactjs, label, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a large label, as shown on the [React Bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/label/):

[image]

However, my labels aren't sizing with the `<h1>` tag they're enclosed in.

Here's my code:

```
<h1>fail<Label bsStyle="danger"> fail </Label> </h1>
```

And this is what my image looks like:

[image: small label meant to be large]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had conflicting CSS code; the error was fixed once I removed it.